# References on creating Charts/Graphs in PHP?

Tags: php, charts, graph

Can anyone suggest a book or a tutorial on creating Charts in PHP extracting the data from MySQL Database. It should not involve Flash in any way.

I dont want to use any pre-built charting solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to look at using the GD image library.

Here's a tutorial to get you started: [Dynamically Creating Graphs and Charts with PHP and GDChart](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3774).

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/mtchart/

Open Source PHP charting library (Fork of pChart, more OO-Code), looks way nicer than the current market leader jpGraph.

(Disclamer/Plug-notification: I'm the developer of mtChart.)

Comment: I always forget to mention: It uses SPACE TECHNOLOGY!

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Can you tell me if I can use your Chart to access data from Mysql database and fill in the values.

Comment: Can you post a tutorial on how to use your Charting, or is it the same a pChart ?

Comment: Basically you can take the examples from pChart and convert them with the help of the migration guide from mtCharts wiki. 

I haven't gotten around to writing better documentation yet.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/intl/iw/apis/visualization/

google visualization

Answer (score 2):

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

Open Source PHP Charting Library. It also has good examples and excellant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can for sure suggest [**jpGraph**](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/features.php) (http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/features.php) , a very complete and well tested library with a number of feature that no other can offer. My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

For some simple charts and graphs I can recommend [HTML_Graphs](http://www.webguys.com/pdavis/Programs/html_graphs/). It is a bit old now but easy to implement, uses straight HTML, and doesn't rely on any third party services or libraries.