# PHP data to chart to image to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, image, charts

I would like to generate a chart from a dataset and eventually put it in a pdf format. How would I go about doing this? Which packages would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution might to go in two steps :

- first, generate the chart, and save it as an image
- then, embed this image in a PDF file

About the first point, there are many questions/answers that might help you ; for instance :

- [Graphs/Charts in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php)
- [What is the best open source PHP charting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528263/what-is-the-best-open-source-php-charting-solution)
- [Free Chart Libraries for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156252/free-chart-libraries-for-php)
- [References on creating Charts/Graphs in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132256/references-on-creating-charts-graphs-in-php)

About the second point, I've not done that quite often, but I suppose [`Zend_Pdf`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html), for instance, could be helpful -- note there are probably other solutions too !

Answer (score 1):

I would look into these:

- [gChartPHP](http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/)
- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)
- [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)
- [Dynamically Generate PDF file with
  PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4044-Dynamically-Generating-PDF-Files-with-PHP-and-Haru-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Diagrams AddOn for fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script28.php).
I've never used it but would give it a try before storing a raster image of a chart in a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert charts in PDF as an image too.
Google's [Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) is deprecated but still works.
A ditto copy of Google's Image Charts is [Image Charts](https://www.image-charts.com) which has free version with their watermark.